# jQuery Function to get RadioButtonList Value

Tags: jquery, asp.net, radiobuttonlist

I have the following HTML code:

```
<tr>
<td>
    <span>Random question here?</span>
</td>
<td>
    <asp:RadioButtonList ID="someList" runat="server" SelectedValue="<%# Bind('someValue') %>" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" CssClass="radioList">
        <asp:ListItem Text="Yes" Value="1"></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Text="No" Value="4"></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Text="Don't Know" Value="2"></asp:ListItem>                                        
    </asp:RadioButtonList>
</td>
<td>
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtSomeValue" runat="server" Height="16px" CssClass="someScore" Enabled="false" Text="0"></asp:TextBox>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtSomeTotal" runat="server" Height="16px" CssClass="someTotal" Enabled="false" Text="0"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:Label ID="lblTFTotal" runat="server" Font-Bold="true" Font-Italic="true" Text="Your selected value is"></asp:Label>
</td>
</tr>
```

I need to write a jQuery function that populates the 'txtSomeValue' TextBox with the value selected from the RadioButtonList, and then calculates all the values selected (from about 10 of these RadioButtonLists) into the 'txtSomeTotal' TextBox.

I'm quite new to jQuery. Any help would be awesome.

Thanks

Comment: Can you show us the HTML output, instead of the ASP server-side code?

Comment: The biggest hint for getting better at jQuery is to use Firebug or the developer tools in any browser to interactively test jQuery code in the JavaScript console. Just keep trying selectors until you get it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your main issue is selecting the radio button as the radiobuttonlist id relates to a table wrapping your radio buttons. Once you've got that it's just a case of getting the fields you want to update. I would suggest assigning a class to the <tr> tag to make this a bit easier:

```
<tr class="mainRow">
<td>
    <span>Random question here?</span>
</td>
<td> ....
```

and then using something like this

```
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.radioList input').click(function () {
            /* get the value of the radio button that's been clicked */
            var selectedValue = $(this).val();
            /* assign it to the nearest text box with a class of someScore */
            $(this).closest('.mainRow').find('.someScore').val(selectedValue);
            /* calculate the value of all the text boxes with a class of someScore */
            var currentTotal = 0;
            $('.someScore').each(function () {
                if (!isNaN($(this).val())) {
                    currentTotal += Number($(this).val());
                }
            });
            /* assign it to the text box that displays the total */
            $('#<%=txtSomeTotal.ClientID %>').val(currentTotal);
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 6):

Ivan almost got it - but there's a quicker way.  Use JQuery to select the RBL, then filter by the selected input:

```
$("#<%# rbRadioButtonListId.ClientID %> input:radio:checked").val();
```

No need for trapping tables or the Name of the radio buttons.

Comment: I had to make one little change: $("#<%=rblThemes.ClientID%> input:radio:checked").val();
So the second # should be a =

Comment: Makes sense. If I remember right, I think I was inside a repeater so I had to use the eval. Good call!

Answer (score 3):

All of the radio buttons in your list should be rendered with the same name attribute. Look at that, and use that as the selector in your script. Something like this should work:

```
$('input:radio[name=NameOfRadioButtons]:checked').val();
```

Answer (score 1):

To populate a textbox with jQuery, you should use the val()-function.

```
$("#ID").val("Text to put in the textbox").
```

Because ASP.NET changes the ID's of the .net-objects, you'll have to do this:

```
$("#<%= txtSomeValue.ClientID %>").val("Text to put in the textbox").
```

Is this sufficient?

Comment: Alternatively, though it is a bit slower, using `$('tag[id$=serverId]')` also works, where "tag" is the HTML tag that gets rendered by the .NET control on the client, and "serverId" is the ID you give the server control. The "$=" means "ends with". Note this isn't as fast as selecting by full ID, but works in a lot more places.

Answer (score 0):

I used:

```
$('#<%= rbRadioButtonListId.ClientID %>').children().children().children().find("input:checked").val();
```

There are too many "children" selectors, because of the generated html for representing the radiobuttonlist (table > tbody > tr > td > input).

Hope this answer will help somebody else, who couldn't find the appropriate solution about his problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
  <asp:RadioButtonList ID="rblRequestType">
        <asp:ListItem Selected="True" Value="value1">Value1</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="Value2">Value2</asp:ListItem>
  </asp:RadioButtonList>
```

You can reach listitems  like this;

```
var radio0 = $("#rblRequestType_0");
var radio1 = $("#rblRequestType_1");

if (radio0.checked){
// do something
}
if (radio1.checked){
// do something
}
```